# sitecore - dot in rich text editor

Tags: sitecore

I'm finding that some strange things are happening with my rich text editor in Sitecore 6.6. Some users have been entering content that is breaking items. Looking at the text it seems fine but when I copy the text into notepad I can see this dot character "·"

Any time this is in the text editor clicking Show Editor does nothing and I can't view raw values either. When I click Edit Html the edit box comes up but my changes will never save, the only way I can seem to fix these pages is if I update the content straight into the database.

Is there a way I can:

1. Prevent these characters from getting into the database,
2. Update the content without having to run update statements on the database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have they been entering this text manually, or is it copy+paste from Word? Possibly the special characters are messing the editor up?

Comment: Agree with @jammykam. If it is a copy+paste from Word or Browser, ask them to paste it to Notepad first and then copy from there to the Editor in Sitecore.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I think the text must have come from an import I did when I first set up the site. I scraped an existing site and it must have come in with some special characters. I'll keep an eye on it thought to make sure no more appear.